# How to speed up nested for-loop logic in Python with Pandas, Numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to check out whether the field of table `TestProject`contains the parameter from the Client-side passed, nested for loop is ugly, is there any efficient and easy way to realize it? Thanks so much for any advice.

```
def test(parameter_a: list, parameter_b: list) -> bool:
    age = TestPeople.age
    project_code = TestProject.project_code
    if age is not None and age <= 16:
        for code in project_code:
            for p in parameter_a:
                if code[:len(p)] == p:
                    return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)?

```
from itertools import product

def test(parameter_a: list, parameter_b: list) -> bool:
    age = TestPeople.age
    project_code = TestProject.project_code
    return (
        age is None 
        or age > 16
        or all(code.startswith(p) for code, p in product(project_code, parameter_a))
    )
```

**EXPLANATION**:

Here python tries to use `short-circuit evaluation`, so it will first check whether `age is None`, if it is, `return True`, otherwise check `age > 16`, if it is `return True` otherwise check if `all` the `code, p` pair match the condition `code.startswith(p)`, if all the pairs pass the condition, `return True`, otherwise if any of the pair fail, `return False` immediately without checking the rest.

Comment: `code.startswith(p)` is cleaner and probably faster than comparing `p` to a slice.

Comment: You still have to return `True` if the condition is false, which can be done with a single expression `return age is None or age > 16 or all(...)`.

Comment: (I was writing up essentially the same answer when I saw yours pop up. :))

Comment: @chepner thanks, forgot about the first if check.

Comment: IMHO it's cleaner to keep the if and `return True` after the `all` block, as in OP.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thanks so much for your quick reply, could you please tell me why you use `or all`? Are you sure it's true and it won't change the original logic? Because I can't verify it right now

Comment: I will add an explanation @FIRE

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thanks so so so much, just confirm again, no need to `return True`, really?

Comment: @FIRE added the explanation. And yes, **no need to explicitly return True.**

Comment: @SayandipDutta  Thanks so much for your detailed answer, I imitated your code just now, but I don't know whether it's correct or not, could you please help me have a look? Thanks so much, I would like to check out If project_code contains parameter_a and product_code contains parameter_b, product_code must contain parameter_c  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407459/how-to-speed-up-nested-for-loop-logic-in-python-with-product

Comment: @SayandipDutta Hi, I found a bug in your code, if age is <= 16, it will return False directly, but my orginal code, it need to match  `all(code.startswith(p) for code, p in product(project_code, parameter_a))` and age <= 16 concurrently.

Comment: No, if `age <= 16` it *will* check for all the matching pairs. Run again with your own example.

Comment: @chepner found a bug in your code, if age is <= 16, it will return False directly, but my orginal code, it need to match  `all(code.startswith(p) for code, p in product(project_code, parameter_a))` and age <= 16 concurrently.

Comment: @Cyttorak Then your code doesn't match my request, what I need is if only `age<=16 and all(code.startswith(p) for code, p in product(project_code, parameter_a)` then return False, it's `and` condition, not `or`

Comment: @FIRE I am not sure why you keep debating this in comments instead of actually running the code on a sample data. Furthermore, I am not checking `age<=16 and all(code.startswith(p) for code, p in product(project_code, parameter_a)`, I am checking `age > 16` **or** `all(code.startswith(p) for code, p in product(project_code, parameter_a)`.  **age greater than 16** and **or**. This will do the same thing you are asking.

Comment: @Cyttorak Sorry, I am not debating It's just because I really appreciate your answer, but it's a pity it doesn't work well in my project, I really want a correct code and answer,  my question is checking `and`, not `or`, and I only if change your code like below, it's ugly, but works `if age is not None and age >= 16 and not all(not code.startswith(p) for code, p in product(project_code, parameter_a)):
        return False
    else:
        return True` ........If you know how to let them beautiful, please updated your answer, thanks again